# disable translatable route object

Tags: 8, routes, meta-tags

I've developed a module which generates and displays dynamic content.
The title of the page is also generated dynamically in the controller as show below:

```
if ($route = $request->attributes->get(\Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_OBJECT)) { 
  $route->setDefault('_title', strval($title))
}
```

This provoques each title is marked as untranslated text and fills the locales_source table.

I tried to use this line to stop this

```
$route->setDefault('_disable_route_normalizer', TRUE)
```

but it doesn't work.

And I tried to use

```
['#title' => $title]
```

and it doesn't work.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a "title" function in your controller and declare it in your route, like here ( _title_callback):

```
entity.node_type.edit_form:
  path: '/admin/structure/types/manage/{node_type}'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'node_type.edit'
    _title_callback: '\Drupal\Core\Entity\Controller\EntityController::title'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer content types'
```

Comment: Or if you buld your routes dynamically like so: $route->setDefault('_title_callback', EntityController::class . '::addBundleTitle');

Comment: Thank's . You put me on the way . 
The solution was this :
`$route->setDefault('_title_callback', function() use($title){ return $title;})`